# What is the convention for the placement of inner classes in java?

Tags: java, coding-style, inner-classes, convention

I have a utility class called Util. Within it I have a MatrixUtil static inner class (among others). Where are inner classes located by convention?

Should MatrixUtil go after Util fields but before Util methods? I was unable to find a java convention on this. Perhaps I missed it in the API...

Anyways, this is the structure I am talking about.

```
public class Util
{
    public static final Vector3f myField;

    public static class MatrixUtil
    {
        public static void myMatrixUtilMethod()
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public static float myUtilMethod()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Code works either way but I'd like to know the proper convention for this. Thanks.

Comment: do whatever you think it's easier to read.

Comment: There is no strong convention for this.

Comment: Okay thanks! I was having trouble finding a convention so thanks for clarifying!

Comment: If interested, there is another [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4730126/3242721) dealing with the same topic. By vote could I would say nested clases belong to the bottom of the file :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always go for the `principle of least surprise`.

When a developer opens your source they will probably be placed at the top of the source. So first comes **the important stuff**.

As they scroll down your source they should next see the **less important stuff**.

Finally, at the end they should find the **unimportant stuff**.

I leave to you the decision as to whether the inner class is **important** or **less important** or **unimportant**.

I would certainly consider inner classes pretty close to **unimportant** especially if they are private - however, if is some kind of factory class that creates and manipulates  objects of that type then they could be considered **important**.

In your case - you seem to be using an inner class to sub-categorize methods - I would not use an inner class to do that, I would use a nested package such as `com.....util.matrixutil`.

Comment: The only reason I avoided a nested package was because that package would only contain one Class. I was under the impression that packages should contain many related classes. For this reason I went with inner classes. Is this approach okay?

Comment: @guyfleeman - A separate package containing just one class which in turn contains just one static method is not malformed - is is merely young. :)

Comment: Even if I have no intention of adding to it in the near future?

Comment: Your intentions will change ... give it time. Besides - you should write your code to outlive you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the majority of the cases are:

- Anonymous inner classes extracted into inner classes for better readability (i.e. `java.util.ArrayList.SubList`, JCF and Guava are full of these).
- Small classes or interfaces related mostly to the enclosing class (i.e. `java.util.Map.Entry`).

I think it's the first time I see an utility inner class, but it's all up to the author. :-)